# Actions Azure CDN configuration for blobstorage Account

Tags: azure, cdn, akamai, blobstorage

i have storage account and what i want is to have firewall ip restriction for the storage account and i have to configure azure CDN(akamai standard) to access storage.i want only the request from CDN should be whitelisted in blobstorage so
(i want to configure cdn ip in the storage firewall settings )
so how can i get CDN IP

I am using Pricing tier : Standard Akamai CDN azure

Answer (score 0):

This might help you
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-standard-rules-engine-match-conditions

This is using Rules Engine in Azure CDN, you will have to see if this is available in Azure Akamai Standard CDN, I think it is though.